# Gradle debug logging

Tags: gradle

How do I use Gradle --debug effectively?

By default just setting the flag outputs so much information that it becomes useless.

I want to just output loggers that I want to see debug info on.

Comment: Can you elaborate about what you mean by _"I want to just output loggers that I want to see debug info on."_? Also, have you tried using the --info flag instead?

Comment: Say I have a custom task I do getProject.getLogger and then log a load of stuff to info and debug. 

But if I use debug then theres so much output from "junk" that I don't want outputted that I can't use that level.

Comment: No offense, but maybe you should reconsider your logging strategy and use info most of the time instead of debug. As a workaround maybe you can add some prefix/tag to your logs so it would be easier for you to filter these out using grep/findstr.

Comment: I do use info but sometimes I want to see additional info... ie debug info!

Comment: Have you worked out how to do it? I have the same issue. Too much output. I just want to see my task's debug info!!